# copying binary file(.jpg) works from command line but not from script

Tags: bash, file-copy

Very simple script to copy a file

```
#!/bin/bash

#copy file
mtp-getfile "6" test2.jpg
```

I set it as executable and run it using

```
sudo sh ./test.sh
```

It gives me a file called test2.jpg that has no icon and I cannot open
I get a 'Failed to open input stream for file' error

However, if I simply issue the following from the command line

`mtp-getfile "6" test2.jpg`

It works as expected.
What is wrong with my script?
I checked and the resulting .jpg file in each case has the same number of bytes. Very strange.

Comment: can you use absolute path for test2.jpg

Comment: if I understand you, it makes no difference. I'm in Desktop.(ubuntu) If I change to mtp-getfile "6" /home/ubuntu-mate/Desktop/foo_absolute.jpg still get a file I can't open if run from .sh script. But works from command line

Comment: did you execute your script with -x ?

Comment: sudo ./test.sh -x  same result

Comment: I wonder if its a permissions issue? When I check permissions of the file I can't open I only see root. Also there is a locked icon

Comment: sudo bash -x test.sh

Comment: no sudo bash -x test.sh makes no difference.

Comment: yep if I do sudo chown <user> <copied file name> it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to do

```
sudo chown <user> <copied file name>
```

Not sure why permissions would be different in each case